# Listar o dono do post e o último usuário que comentou. Mysql

Tags: mysql, query, select

Eai galera, eu tenho a seguinte query abaixo, onde eu listo todos os posts, quantidade de comentários e o usuário que o criou, mas também queria listar o último usuário que comentou cada post, será que dá pra fazer tudo isso em apenas uma query?

```
SELECT post.titulo, COUNT(comentario.codigo), autor.nome, MAX(comentario.codigo_usuario) FROM post JOIN comentario JOIN usuario autor JOIN usuario ON post.codigo_usuario = autor.codigo AND post.codigo = comentario.codigo_topico AND usuario.codigo = comentario.codigo_usuario GROUP BY post.codigo
```

Comment: Só uma observação, se for para usar JOIN, acho que fica mais interessante com a cláusula ON em vez de WHERE: `JOIN comentario ON post.codigo = comentario.codigo_post JOIN usuario ON ...`. Ou, se prefere mesmo o WHERE, não precisa de JOIN, separe as tabelas com vírgula `FROM post, comentario, usuario WHERE post.codigo`. Claro que você deve fazer como achar melhor, a sugestão é só no sentido de "padronizar", caso ache interessante.

Comment: Uma possibilidade seria, supondo que os comentários tenham ID em  ordem temporal usar um novo JOIN vinculando o MAX( comentario.id ) novamente à tabela comentários, e obtendo o ID do comentarista. Alternativamente, no MySQL dá pra usar o ORDER BY ... DESC para o GROUP pegar o ultimo de uma determinada tabela, mas não é garantido que isso funcionará em versões futuras

Comment: Irei utilizar ON então. Não entendi muito bem o que tu disse, não to conseguindo pegar o nome de quem criou o post e ao mesmo tempo pegar o nome do ultimo q comentou, e o ORDER BY eu vou utilizar para ordenar pelo nome do post.

Comment: Lembre-se que nada impede de fazer ORDER BY nome, post.id DESC, por exemplo (ordenando prioritariamente pelo nome, mas deixando o ID decrescente do post como 2º fator de ordenação). O ORDER BY pode aceitar várias expressões e/ou colunas diferentes separadas por vírgula.

Comment: Quanto a pegar os nomes separadamente, se ambos forem da tabela usuário, precisa dar JOIN duas vezes JOIN usuario AS autor ON... JOIN usuario AS comentarista ON ...

Comment: Não sabia que dava pra usar duas cláusulas no ORDER BY. Editei o post colocando como está a query, eu usei o MAX para pegar o codigo do ultimo usuario q comentou, mas como eu uso esse codigo para comparar com a tabela usuario(para pegar o nome)? Já que só da pra usar o MAX no select e não no ON

Comment: Conseguir fazer, coloquei um "usuario.codigo = (select max(codigo_usuario) from comentario where comentario.codigo_post = post.codigo" para fazer a comparação com o código do usuário. Valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score -2):

Dá pa fazer, precisas de ter um atributo do genero DATE ou DATETIME, que te guarda a data em que o post foi feito, tudo depende como tens construido a base de dados

Comment: Eu tenho um campo de data, mas não consigo imaginar como mudar esse select para listar somente o ultimo que comentou.